# Can't solve a problem in pine script editor

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I'm working on a Script that detects rsi divergence.
Sometimes he can't find it, just like in the image.
How can I solve this problem?
If you are interested, I can share the code with you

Not Working :
[image]

Working :
[image]

i tried to change the rsi values, I tried to change the pivot levels, I asked chat gpt to solve it, but it couldn't

```
    //@version=5

// Burada indikatörümüzün kimliği, tanımladığımız veri setleri ve bazı değişkenler bulunuyor.

indicator(title='RSI Uyumsuzluk İndikatörü V2.0 - Yunus)', shorttitle='Uyumsuzluk İndikatörü - Yunus', overlay=false)

len = input.int(title='RSI Period', minval=1, defval=6)
src = input(title='RSI Source', defval=close)
lbR = input(title='Pivot Lookback Right', defval=4)
lbL = input(title='Pivot Lookback Left', defval=4)

// Burada yazılan RSI göstergesi Tradingview'in orijinal göstergesi, 100% doğru çalışması için farklı bir gösterge tercih edilmedi.

ma(source, length, type) =>
    switch type
        "SMA" => ta.sma(source, length)
        "Bollinger Bands" => ta.sma(source, length)
        "EMA" => ta.ema(source, length)
        "SMMA (RMA)" => ta.rma(source, length)
        "WMA" => ta.wma(source, length)
        "VWMA" => ta.vwma(source, length)

rsiLengthInput = input.int(6, minval=1, title="RSI Length", group="RSI Settings")
rsiSourceInput = input.source(close, "Source", group="RSI Settings")
maTypeInput = input.string("SMA", title="MA Type", options=["WMA", "Bollinger Bands", "EMA", "SMMA (RMA)", "SMA", "VWMA"], group="MA Settings")
maLengthInput = input.int(14, title="MA Length", group="MA Settings")
bbMultInput = input.float(2.0, minval=0.001, maxval=50, title="BB StdDev", group="MA Settings")

up = ta.rma(math.max(ta.change(rsiSourceInput), 0), rsiLengthInput)
down = ta.rma(-math.min(ta.change(rsiSourceInput), 0), rsiLengthInput)
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))
rsiMA = ma(rsi, maLengthInput, maTypeInput)
isBB = maTypeInput == "Bollinger Bands"

//Bu kısım RSI hatlarının grafiğe dönüştürüldüğü kısım. 
//Dilin yapısı sebebiyle buradaki renk değişimleri grafik üzerindeki menüden yapılabilir.

plot(rsi, "RSI", color.new(color.white, 10))
plot(rsiMA, "RSI-based MA", color=color.yellow)
rsiUpperBand = hline(70, "RSI Upper Band", color=#787B86)
hline(50, "RSI Middle Band", color=color.new(#787B86, 50))
rsiLowerBand = hline(30, "RSI Lower Band", color=#787B86)
fill(rsiUpperBand, rsiLowerBand, color=color.rgb(126, 87, 194, 90), title="RSI Background Fill")
bbUpperBand = plot(isBB ? rsiMA + ta.stdev(rsi, maLengthInput) * bbMultInput : na, title = "Upper Bollinger Band", color=color.green)
bbLowerBand = plot(isBB ? rsiMA - ta.stdev(rsi, maLengthInput) * bbMultInput : na, title = "Lower Bollinger Band", color=color.green)
fill(bbUpperBand, bbLowerBand, color= isBB ? color.new(color.green, 90) : na, title="Bollinger Bands Background Fill")

// Bu kısım uyumsuzluk tespiti için kullandığımız uzun çizgilerin ve sinyal çizgilerinin grafiğe dönüştürüldüğü kısım.

// ------------------

// rangeUpper ve rangeLower, yalnızca pivotların aranacağı bar aralığını belirler. Varsayılan olarak, rangeUpper 60 ve rangeLower 5 olarak ayarlanmıştır.
// Grafiğin çizileceği pivot aralığı kullanıcının isteğiyle TV içerisindeki panelden ayarlanabilir.

rangeUpper = input(title='Max of Lookback Range', defval=50)
rangeLower = input(title='Min of Lookback Range', defval=6)

// ------------------

//plotBull, plotHiddenBull, plotBear ve plotHiddenBear girdileri, hangi tür pivotlerin grafiğe çizileceğini belirler. 
//Varsayılan olarak, bu girdilerin tümü true olarak ayarlanmıştır, yani grafiğe tüm pivot tipleri çizilir.

plotBull = input(title='Plot Bullish', defval=true)
plotHiddenBull = input(title='Plot Hidden Bullish', defval=false)
plotBear = input(title='Plot Bearish', defval=true)
plotHiddenBear = input(title='Plot Hidden Bearish', defval=false)

// ------------------

bearColor = color.red
bullColor = color.green
hiddenBullColor = color.green
hiddenBearColor = color.red
textColor = color.white
noneColor = color.new(color.white, 100)

osc = ta.rsi(src, len)

plFound = na(ta.pivotlow(osc, lbL, lbR)) ? false : true
phFound = na(ta.pivothigh(osc, lbL, lbR)) ? false : true

_inRange(cond) =>
    bars = ta.barssince(cond == true)
    rangeLower <= bars and bars <= rangeUpper

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////----------\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
// ----------------------------- Bu satırın altındaki kodlar uyumsuzluğu hesaplama ve grafikte etiketlemek üzerinedir. -------------------------- \\


// Regular Bullish, Türkçe ismiyle normal boğa.

// Osc: Higher Low
oscHL = osc[lbR] > ta.valuewhen(plFound, osc[lbR], 1) and _inRange(plFound[1])

// Price: Lower Low
priceLL = low[lbR] < ta.valuewhen(plFound, low[lbR], 1)

bullCond = plotBull and priceLL and oscHL and plFound

plot(plFound ? osc[lbR] : na, offset=-lbR, title='Regular Bullish', linewidth=2, color=bullCond ? bullColor : noneColor, transp=0)

//üstteki plot ile başlayan satırı özellikle öyle bıraktım, v5'deki haliyle yazınca kod patlıyor.

plotshape(bullCond ? osc[lbR] : na, offset=-lbR, title='Regular Bullish Label', text=' Bull ', style=shape.labelup, location=location.absolute, color=color.new(bullColor, 0), textcolor=color.new(textColor, 0))

// ------------------

// Hidden Bullish, Türkçe ismiyle gizli boğa.

// Osc: Lower Low
oscLL = osc[lbR] < ta.valuewhen(plFound, osc[lbR], 1) and _inRange(plFound[1])

// Price: Higher Low
priceHL = low[lbR] > ta.valuewhen(plFound, low[lbR], 1)

hiddenBullCond = plotHiddenBull and priceHL and oscLL and plFound

plot(plFound ? osc[lbR] : na, offset=-lbR, title='Hidden Bullish', linewidth=2, color=hiddenBullCond ? hiddenBullColor : noneColor, transp=0)

//üstteki plot ile başlayan satırı özellikle öyle bıraktım, v5'deki haliyle yazınca kod patlıyor.

plotshape(hiddenBullCond ? osc[lbR] : na, offset=-lbR, title='Hidden Bullish Label', text=' H Bull ', style=shape.labelup, location=location.absolute, color=color.new(bullColor, 0), textcolor=color.new(textColor, 0))

// ------------------

// Regular Bearish, Türkçe ismiyle normal ayı.

// Osc: Lower High
oscLH = osc[lbR] < ta.valuewhen(phFound, osc[lbR], 1) and _inRange(phFound[1])

// Price: Higher High
priceHH = high[lbR] > ta.valuewhen(phFound, high[lbR], 1)

bearCond = plotBear and priceHH and oscLH and phFound

plot(phFound ? osc[lbR] : na, offset=-lbR, title='Regular Bearish', linewidth=2, color=bearCond ? bearColor : noneColor, transp=0)

//üstteki plot ile başlayan satırı özellikle öyle bıraktım, v5'deki haliyle yazınca kod patlıyor.

plotshape(bearCond ? osc[lbR] : na, offset=-lbR, title='Regular Bearish Label', text=' Bear ', style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.new(bearColor, 0), textcolor=color.new(textColor, 0))

// ------------------

// Hidden Bearish, Türkçe ismiyle gizli ayı.

// Osc: Higher High
oscHH = osc[lbR] > ta.valuewhen(phFound, osc[lbR], 1) and _inRange(phFound[1])

// Price: Lower High
priceLH = high[lbR] < ta.valuewhen(phFound, high[lbR], 1)

hiddenBearCond = plotHiddenBear and priceLH and oscHH and phFound

plot(phFound ? osc[lbR] : na, offset=-lbR, title='Hidden Bearish', linewidth=2, color=hiddenBearCond ? hiddenBearColor : noneColor, transp=0)

plotshape(hiddenBearCond ? osc[lbR] : na, offset=-lbR, title='Hidden Bearish Label', text=' H Bear ', style=shape.labeldown, location=location.absolute, color=color.new(bearColor, 0), textcolor=color.new(textColor, 0))

//\\ ---------------------------- Bu satırın üstündeki kodlar uyumsuzluğu hesaplama ve grafikte etiketlemek üzerinedir. ------------------------- //\\

///\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\----------/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////\\\
```

Comment: I tried your code, it is working. Can you be more specific about the problem you have ? (on which pair, timeframe, when )